# Oracle 11g: functions or procedures in C/C++

Tags: postgresql, oracle, oracle-11g-r2, stored-procedures, functions

I want to create a function called by a trigger on oracle but in c or c++. Something like in PostgreSQL: [Audit trigger in C](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_c).

Or, in any case, is there support for this but in other languages like Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle database supports Java and external C calls. They can be used as wrappers to call programs written in other languages such as Python.

[Publishing External Procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_externproc.htm#ADFNS1405)

> Oracle Database can only use external procedures that are published
>   through a call specification, which maps names, parameter types, and
>   return types for your Java class method or C external procedure to
>   their SQL counterparts.

Create a sample program:

```
$ cat /home/oracle/1.c
char* myfunc()
{
   return "Hello World!";
}

$ gcc -shared -o /home/oracle/1.so -fPIC /home/oracle/1.c
```

In the database, create a library and a function using it:

```
create or replace library lib_myfunc is '/home/oracle/1.so';
/

create or replace function myfunc
return varchar2 as external
name "myfunc"
library lib_myfunc
language c;
/
```

Enable the use of this library in `$ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin/extproc.ora`:

```
SET EXTPROC_DLLS=/home/oracle/1.so
```

Then finally use it as:

```
SQL> select myfunc from dual;

MYFUNC
------------
Hello World!
```

More about this:

[Developing Applications with Multiple Programming Languages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_externproc.htm#ADFNS010)